# My team is moving to TFS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2005

My team is moving to TFS 2008, but all of our old projects are from our stand alone VS 2005. We did not have Team Server. Can put our projects under source control in TFS 2008 without upgrading and migrating them?

Answer (score 0):

Using VS2005 you can check-in old projects into TFS 2008 but if you open them with VS2008 it will ask you to convert the project to the newer format.